# Show particular record in first row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
Select ShipViaCode 
from tbl_VW_Epicor_ShipVia_Master
```

and I am getting this output:

```
AIR
CHRT
COMP
CO20
Co40
CSPU
FEDX
NFRT
ser
TRCK
```

I want to get my first row as 'TRCK', so how can I re-write the query?

Answer (score 2):

```
Select ShipViaCode from tbl_VW_Epicor_ShipVia_Master order by ShipViaCode desc;
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ShipViaCode from tbl_VW_Epicor_ShipVia_Master
order by (case when ShipViaCode = 'TRCK' then 0 else 1 end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort you result by that column but in descending order,

```
Select ShipViaCode from tbl_VW_Epicor_ShipVia_Master order by ShipViaCode desc
```